# Map a function that takes arguments in different levels of a list

Tags: map

I would like to map a function that takes as an argument a list in a list of lists and an element of the list of lists. 
So for example, this is my list of lists:

> {{4,1},  {3,1,1},  {2,2,1}}

I would like to map the function to the list of lists to obtain the following outcome:

> { {f[{4,1},4],  f[{4,1},1]},  {f[{3,1,1},3}],  f[{3,1,1},1],  f[{3,1,1},1] }, {f[{2,2,1},2], f[{2,2,1},2], f[{2,2,1},1]}

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to do it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[g1,  f]
g1 = Function[x, f[x, #] & /@ x]

lst = {{4, 1}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}};

g1 /@ lst
```

> {{f[{4, 1}, 4], f[{4, 1}, 1]},
>   {f[{3, 1, 1}, 3], f[{3, 1, 1}, 1], f[{3, 1, 1}, 1]},
>   {f[{2, 2, 1}, 2], f[{2, 2, 1}, 2], f[{2, 2, 1}, 1]}}

Also

```
ClearAll[g2, g3, g4]

g2[x_]:= Map[f[x, #] &] @ x
g2 /@ lst


g3 = Thread[f[#, #], List, {2}] & 
g3 /@ lst

g4[x_, y_] := f[x, #] & /@ y
g4[#, #] & /@ lst
```

Answer (score 7):

```
lst = {{4, 1}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}};
Table[Table[f[i, j], {j, i}], {i, lst}]
```

> {{f[{4, 1}, 4], f[{4, 1}, 1]}, {f[{3, 1, 1}, 3], f[{3, 1, 1}, 1], 
>     f[{3, 1, 1}, 1]}, {f[{2, 2, 1}, 2], f[{2, 2, 1}, 2], 
>     f[{2, 2, 1}, 1]}}

Comment: +1.  also: `Table[f[i, j], {i, lst}, {j, i}]`

Comment: @WReach Yes, good point!

Answer (score 7):

I like the techniques in the other answers (particularly the `Table` approach in [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204659/142) by [MelaGo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/63360/melago)), but here are a few other options to add to the mix...

Given:

```
$list = {{4,1}, {3,1,1}, {2,2,1}};
```

Then any of the following expressions yield the desired result:

```
Curry[f, 2][#] /@ # & /@ $list
```

or

```
Cases[$list, l_ :> (f[l, #] & /@ l)]
```

or

```
Replace[$list, l_ :> (f[l, #] & /@ l), {1}]
```

or

```
MapIndexed[f[$list[[#2[[1]]]], #] &, $list, {2}]
```

or

```
ReplacePart[$list, {i_, j_} :> f[$list[[i]], $list[[i, j]]]]
```

Comment: In version 12.1, _Curry_ has been renamed to _OperatorApplied_.